# Using global namespace qualifiers with pointer to data members

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm experiencing a compile error when attempting to use a [pointer to data member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) when including the global namespace qualifier on the struct. I've reduced my code to the following, which **works**:

```cpp
namespace foo {
  using sausage = int;
  struct bar { sausage baz; };
}

auto chuckle(foo::bar barry, ::foo::sausage foo::bar::*paul) {
  return barry.*paul;
}

int main() {
  return chuckle(foo::bar{5}, &foo::bar::baz);
}
```

If I now add the global namespace qualifier to the `bar` struct in the argument to `chuckle`:

```cpp
auto chuckle(foo::bar barry, ::foo::sausage ::foo::bar::*paul) {
                                        //  ^~ added ::
  return barry.*paul;
}
```

...then it no longer compiles and fails with the following error:

```
10 : <source>:10:37: error: 'foo::sausage' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
 auto chuckle(foo::bar barry, ::foo::sausage ::foo::bar::*paul) {
                                     ^~~~~~~
10 : <source>:10:57: error: expected identifier before '*' token
 auto chuckle(foo::bar barry, ::foo::sausage ::foo::bar::*paul) {
                                                         ^
<source>: In function 'auto chuckle(foo::bar, int*)':
11 : <source>:11:17: error: 'paul' cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type 'int*'
   return barry.*paul;
                 ^~~~
<source>: In function 'int main()':
15 : <source>:15:45: error: cannot convert 'foo::sausage foo::bar::* {aka int foo::bar::*}' to 'int*' for argument '2' to 'auto chuckle(foo::bar, int*)'
   return chuckle(foo::bar{5}, &foo::bar::baz);
                                             ^
```

I see this behaviour across MSVC, Clang and GCC.

I've put both examples on Godbolt:

- [working example](https://godbolt.org/g/2AWngA)
- [failing example](https://godbolt.org/g/b7ArL3)

### Questions

a) Why does adding the global namespace qualifier cause the compilation to fail?

b) Is there a reason for this in the language specification?

Comment: How did I miss this question! So much barry...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Subtle issue!

The compiler does not consider extra whitespace, so your code is actually:

```
auto chuckle(foo::bar barry, ::foo::sausage::foo::bar::*paul)
```

... which, of course, does not make sense. You need to disambiguate with parentheses:

```
auto chuckle(foo::bar barry, ::foo::sausage (::foo::bar::*paul))
//                                          ^                 ^
```

... and everything is fine.

If you're not into parentheses, [@Paula_plus_plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393773/using-global-namespace-qualifiers-with-pointer-to-data-members/47394016?noredirect=1#comment81746702_47394016) has you covered with a dummy attribute, which can actually be empty as [@T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393773/using-global-namespace-qualifiers-with-pointer-to-data-members/47394016?noredirect=1#comment86149082_47394016) helpfully points out:

```
auto chuckle(foo::bar barry, ::foo::sausage [[]] ::foo::bar::*paul)
//                                          ^^^^
```

The compiler is required to ignore it silently, but it does solve the problem for the parser.

Comment: this is a case where a good formatter helps. clang-formatter removes the space, thus revealing the issue.

Comment: @Quentin: Yep, that fixes things. I hadn't considered that it shares the syntax with function pointers. Looking at it like that, I can see the ambiguity now. Thank you! :)

Comment: Will it work with a dummy attribute as well? `auto chuckle(foo::bar barry, ::foo::sausage [[dummy]] ::foo::bar::*paul)`

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster as horrible as it is, it does work! May I include it in the answer?

Comment: @Quentin as long as you're happy with it (even if it is horrible) include it in the answer ;)

Comment: The compiler is required to ignore an attribute it doesn't recognize. But it may do so with much fanfare. Or claim to recognize every attribute with the behavior "renders the program ill-formed".

Comment: @T.C. ... really? I know we're keen on our undefined behaviours, but why would an implementation be allowed to do that?

Comment: You don't actually need an attribute in there. `[[]]` will do. (And as to the attribute question, nobody knows how to ban it. And you may well want a warning that the compiler isn't recognizing an attribute you are using.)